# console.log(form) returns undefined for Angular 7 form

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular form with several fields including radio buttons, selects, inputs. I have an onSubmit() function that's called when I submit the form. Within this function I have a console.log(form). When checking the console on google's debugger, I see that the value returned from the console log is undefined.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, HostBinding } from "@angular/core";
import { NgForm } from "@angular/forms";
import { Person, Name, Address } from "../app/models/person";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"];

export class AppComponent {

  title = "pardon";
  provinces = [
    "Alberta",
    "British Columbia",
    "Manitoba",
    "New Brunswick",
    "Newfoundland and Labrador",
    "Northwest Territories",
    "Nova Scotia",
    "Nunavut",
    "Ontario",
    "Prince Edward Island",
    "Quebec",
    "Saskatchewan",
    "Yukon"
  ];

  person: Person;
  name: Name;
  date: Date;
  address: Address;


  nameCap: number;
  cap: boolean;

  showDelete: boolean;
  showNameInput: boolean;
  showAddressInput: boolean;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.person = new Person();
    this.person.fullName = new Name();
    this.person.currentAddress = new Address();
    this.person.previousAddress = [];
    this.person.alias = [];

    this.showDelete = false;
    this.showNameInput = false;
    this.showAddressInput = false;

    this.nameCap = 1;
    this.cap = false;
  }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    console.log(form);
  }

  addName() {
    this.person.alias.push({ firstName: "", lastName: "" });
    this.showDelete = true;
    this.showNameInput = true;
    this.nameCap++;
    if (this.nameCap > 4) {
      this.cap = true;
    }
  }

  addAddress(){
    this.person.previousAddress.push({ streetAddress: "", city: "", province: "", country: "", postalCode: ""});
    this.showAddressInput = true;
  }

  trackByName(index: number, person: any) {
    return person.id;
  }

  removeName(i: number) {
    this.person.alias.splice(i, 1);
    this.nameCap--;
    if (this.nameCap <= 4) {
      this.cap = false;
    }
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="card card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title bg-success">Pardon Application Electronic Form</h4>
          <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
          <div id="user-data" 
             ngModelGroup="userData"
             #userData="ngModelGroup">
             <div class="card card-body bg-info">
                <h4 class="card-title bg-primary">Section A: Personal Information</h4>
                <div class="card-text form-inline">
                   <label for="firstname">First name</label>&nbsp;
                   <input
                   type="text" 
                   id="firstname" 
                   class="form-control"
                   [(ngModel)]="person.fullName.firstName"
                   name="firstName"
                   required
                   #firstName="ngModel">
                   <span class="help-block" *ngIf="!firstName.valid && firstName.touched">Please enter your first name</span>
                   &nbsp;
                   <label for="lastname">Last name</label>&nbsp;
                   <input
                   type="text"
                   id="lastname"
                   class="form-control"
                   [(ngModel)]="person.fullName.lastName"
                   name="lastName"
                   required
                   #lastName="ngModel">
                   <span class="help-block" *ngIf="!lastName.valid && lastName.touched">Please enter your last name</span>
                   &nbsp;
                   <label>Have you ever used another name other than your legal name above?</label>&nbsp;
                   <div class="radio">
                      <label>
                      <input
                      type="radio"
                      name="hasAlias"
                      [value]=true
                      [(ngModel)]="person.hasAlias"
                      #hasAlias="ngModel">
                      Yes
                      </label>&nbsp;
                   </div>
                   <div class="radio">
                      <label>
                      <input
                      type="radio"
                      name="hasAlias"
                      [value]=false
                      [(ngModel)]="person.hasAlias"
                      #hasAlias="ngModel">
                      No
                      </label>
                   </div>
                   <div *ngIf="person.hasAlias">
                      <br>
                      <div class="wrapper">
                         <button class="buttonAlign" [disabled]="cap"
                         class="btn help-block btn-warning" 
                         type="button"
                         id="addName"
                         (click)="addName()">Add more names
                         </button>
                      </div>
                      <div *ngIf="showNameInput">
                         <div ngModelGroup="alias">
                            <div class="box2" *ngFor="let a of person.alias; let i = index; trackBy: trackByName">
                               <!-- style="width: 100px; height: 100px" [@divState]="state"  -->
                               <div [ngModelGroup]="i">
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                     <label for="firstNameAlias">First name</label>
                                     <input
                                     type="text"
                                     id="firstName"
                                     class="form-control"
                                     [(ngModel)]="a.firstName"
                                     name="firstName"
                                     #firstName="ngModel">
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                     <label for="lastNameAlias">Last name</label>
                                     <input
                                     type="text"
                                     id="lastName"
                                     class="form-control"
                                     [(ngModel)]="a.lastName"
                                     name="lastName"
                                     #lastName="ngModel">
                                  </div>
                               </div>
                               <button
                                  class="btn help-block btn-danger"
                                  type="button"
                                  id="removeName"
                                  (click)="removeName(i)">Remove name
                               </button>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <br>
             </div>
             <div class="card card-body bg-warning">
                <div class="card-text">
                   <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                         <label>Sex</label>
                         <select class="form-control">
                         <option *ngFor="let s of person.sex"
                         name="sex"
                         [value]="sex"
                         [(ngModel)]="person.sex"
                         #sex="ngModel"
                         ngDefaultControl>{{s}}
                         </option> 
                         </select>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                         <label>Date of Birth</label>
                         <div class="form-group form-inline">
                            <input
                            type="date"
                            name="person.dob"
                            [(ngModel)]="person.dob"
                            #dob="ngModel"
                            required>
                         </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                         <label>Were you born in Canada?</label>
                         <div class="radio">
                            <label>
                            <input
                            type="radio"
                            name="person.canadianBorn"
                            [value]=true
                            [(ngModel)]="person.canadianBorn"
                            #canadianBorn="ngModel">
                            Yes
                            </label>
                         </div>
                         <div class="radio">
                            <label>
                            <input
                            type="radio"
                            name="person.canadianBorn"
                            [value]=false
                            [(ngModel)]="person.canadianBorn"
                            #canadianBorn="ngModel">
                            No
                            </label>
                         </div>
                         <div *ngIf="person.canadianBorn">
                            Born in Canada!
                         </div>
                         <div *ngIf="person.canadianBorn==false">
                            See STEP 5 of the Record Suspension application Guide
                         </div>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
             <div class="card card-body bg-info">
                <div class="card-text">
                   <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                         <label>Do you have a driver's license?</label>
                         <div class="radio">
                            <label>
                            <input
                            type="radio"
                            name="person.hasLicense"
                            [value]=true
                            [(ngModel)]="person.hasLicense"
                            #hasLicense="ngModel">
                            Yes
                            </label>
                         </div>
                         <div class="radio">
                            <label>
                            <input
                            type="radio"
                            name="person.hasLicense"
                            [value]=false
                            [(ngModel)]="person.hasLicense"
                            #hasLicense="ngModel">
                            No
                            </label>
                         </div>
                         <div *ngIf="person.hasLicense">
                            <label>Driver's License Number</label>
                            <input type="text"
                            class="form-control"
                            placeholder="A1234-56789-12345"
                            id="name"
                            name="person.licenseNumber"
                            [(ngModel)]="person.licenseNumber"
                            #licenseNumber="ngModel">
                            <label for="province">Province issued</label>
                            <select
                               id="province"
                               class="form-control"
                               ngModel
                               name="provinceIssued">
                               <option *ngFor="let province of provinces">
                                  {{province}}
                               </option>
                            </select>
                         </div>
                         <br>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                         <label>Are you employed?</label>
                         <div class="radio">
                            <label>
                            <input
                            type="radio"
                            name="person.employed"
                            [value]=true
                            [(ngModel)]="person.employed"
                            #employed="ngModel">
                            Yes
                            </label>
                         </div>
                         <div class="radio">
                            <label>
                            <input
                            type="radio"
                            name="person.employed"
                            [value]=false
                            [(ngModel)]="person.employed"
                            #employed="ngModel">
                            No
                            </label>
                         </div>
                         <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                            <input
                            type="checkbox"
                            name="person.selfEmployed"
                            [value]=true
                            [(ngModel)]="person.selfEmployed"
                            #selfEmployed="ngModel">
                            I am self employed
                            </label>
                         </div>
                         <div *ngIf="person.employed">
                            <label>Employer name</label>
                            <input type="text"
                            class="form-control"
                            id="employer"
                            name="person.employer"
                            [(ngModel)]="person.employer"
                            #employer="ngModel">
                         </div>
                         <div *ngIf="person.selfEmployed">
                            <label>Your company name and/or number</label>
                            <input type="text"
                            class="form-control"
                            id="company"
                            name="person.company"
                            [(ngModel)]="person.company"
                            #company="ngModel">
                         </div>
                         <br>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
             <div class="card card-body bg-warning">
                <h4 class="card-title bg-primary">Section B: Correspondence and Residence Information</h4>
                <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                         <label>Street Address</label>
                         <input type="text"
                         class="form-control"
                         [(ngModel)]="person.currentAddress.streetAddress"
                         #streetAddress="ngModel"
                         name="streetAddress">
                      </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="form-group">
                         <label>City</label>
                         <input type="text"
                         class="form-control"
                         [(ngModel)]="person.currentAddress.city"
                         #city="ngModel"
                         name="city">
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div class="form-group">
                         <label>Province</label>
                         <input type="text"
                         class="form-control"
                         [(ngModel)]="person.currentAddress.province"
                         #province="ngModel"
                         name="province">
                      </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div class="form-group">
                         <label>Country</label>&nbsp;
                         <input type="text"
                         class="form-control"
                         [(ngModel)]="person.currentAddress.country"
                         #country="ngModel"
                         name="country">
                      </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div class="form-group">
                         <label>Postal Code</label>
                         <input type="text"
                         class="form-control"
                         [(ngModel)]="person.currentAddress.postalCode"
                         #postalCode="ngModel"
                         name="postalCode">
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="wrapper">
                   <button class="buttonAlign"
                      class="btn help-block btn-warning" 
                      type="button"
                      >Verify Address
                   </button>
                </div>
             </div>
             <div class="card-body bg-info">
                <label>Do you want information in English or French?</label>
                <select class="form-control">
                <option *ngFor="let lang of person.language"
                name="language"
                [value]="language"
                [(ngModel)]="person.language"
                #language="ngModel"
                ngDefaultControl>
                {{lang}}
                </option>
                </select>
                <!-- <div class="radio" *ngFor="let lang of person.language">
                   <label>
                   <input 
                   type="radio"
                   name="language"
                   [(ngModel)]="person.language"
                   [value]="lang"
                   required>
                   {{ lang }}
                   </label>
                   </div> -->
                <label>Have you lived at an address different from the one entered above, within the last 10 years?</label>
                <div class="radio">
                   <label>
                   <input
                   type="radio"
                   name="person.moreAddresses"
                   [value]=true
                   [(ngModel)]="person.moreAddresses"
                   #moreAddresses="ngModel">
                   Yes
                   </label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio">
                   <label>
                   <input
                   type="radio"
                   name="person.moreAddresses"
                   [value]=false
                   [(ngModel)]="person.moreAddresses"
                   #moreAddresses="ngModel">
                   No
                   </label>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body bg-warning" *ngIf="person.moreAddresses">
                   <div class="wrapper">
                      <button class="buttonAlign" 
                         class="btn help-block btn-warning" 
                         type="button"
                         id="addAddress"
                         (click)="addAddress()">Add an address
                      </button>
                   </div>
                   <br>
                   <div *ngFor="let addy of person.previousAddress">
                      <div class="row" *ngIf="showAddressInput">
                         <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                               <label>Street Address</label>
                               <input type="text"
                               class="form-control"
                               [(ngModel)]="person.currentAddress.streetAddress"
                               #streetAddress="ngModel"
                               name="streetAddress"> 
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                               <label>City</label>
                               <input type="text"
                               class="form-control"
                               [(ngModel)]="person.currentAddress.city"
                               #city="ngModel"
                               name="city">
                            </div>
                         </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row" *ngIf="showAddressInput">
                         <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                               <label>Province</label>
                               <input type="text"
                               class="form-control"
                               [(ngModel)]="person.currentAddress.province"
                               #province="ngModel"
                               name="province">
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                               <label>Country</label>&nbsp;
                               <input type="text"
                               class="form-control"
                               [(ngModel)]="person.currentAddress.country"
                               #country="ngModel"
                               name="country">
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                               <label>Postal Code</label>
                               <input type="text"
                               class="form-control"
                               [(ngModel)]="person.currentAddress.postalCode"
                               #postalCode="ngModel"
                               name="postalCode">
                            </div>
                         </div>
                      </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
          </form>
       </div>
       <button 
       class="btn btn-primary" 
       type="submit"
       [disabled]="!f.valid"
       (click)="onSubmit()"
       >Submit
       </button>
    </div>
 </div>
```

person.ts

```
export class Person {
    public fullName: Name;
    public alias: Name[];

    public currentAddress: Address;
    public previousAddress: Address[];

    public canadianBorn: boolean;
    public hasLicense: boolean;
    public licenseNumber: number;
    public hasAlias: boolean;
    public employed: boolean;
    public employer: string;
    public selfEmployed: boolean;
    public sex = ['Male', 'Female', 'Other'];
    public language = ['English', 'Francais'];
    public moreAddresses: boolean;
    public dob = Date;
    public company: string;
}

export class Name {
    public firstName: string;
    public lastName: string;
}

export class Address {
    public streetAddress: string;
    public city: string;
    public province: string;
    public country: string;
    public postalCode: string;
}
```

Comment: In your HTML you have `(click)="onSubmit()"`. You're not passing in any arguments when you submit the form on the click event. Also you really should consider using [Angular Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) or [Angular Template Driven Forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms). It will save you a lot of headache.

Comment: @Narm thanks! silly of me to miss that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(click)="onSubmit()"
I did not pass any arguments on the click event, hence why the console.log was returning undefined.

Passing the argument "f" (click)="onSubmit(f)" achieved the desired results of outputting the form data.

Answer (score 0):

Use your submit button like so:

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!f.valid">Submit</button>
```

Log Template-driven form value:

```
console.log(form)
```

Log Reactive form value:

```
console.log(form.value)
```